# Help understanding const char* operators in c++

Tags: java, c++, string, operators, translation

I need to translate some code from c++ to java, and I am not so sure how to deal with the 'const char*' operators. Check code below:

```
const char* handText;
const char* index = strchr(handText, '-');
char handCeil[4];
char handFloor[4];
strncpy(handCeil, handText, index - handText);
strcpy(handFloor, index + 1);
```

What I got is something like:

```
String handText;
String index = handText.substring(handText.indexOf('-'));
char handCeil[4];
char handFloor[4];
```

However, I don't know what it means when you add integers (index + 1), or when you subtract (index - handText) strings in c++. Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I never learned how to program in c++, only in java. Thank you.

Comment: I am not entirely sure about your question, but you are not using "strings" in C++, you are using char* in C++... If you want to use strings in C++ in the sense of Java (or as close to possible as Java) #include <string> and use the methods from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
strncpy(handCeil, handText, index - handText);
strcpy(handFloor, index + 1);
```

is equivalent to

```
int index = handText.indexOf('-'); // I changed this for you
handCeil = handText.substring(0, index+1);
handFloor = handText.substring(index+1);
```

So it splits the string by the '-' and puts the first part (including the '-' itself, I think) into `handCeil` and the remainder into `handFloor`.

`index - handText` means this: `index` points to a specific character, `handText` points to the beginning of that string. If you subtract the two then you get the number of characters between those two pointers, or the array index of the first '-'. `strncpy` copies `n` bytes, so if `index` points to the 3rd character it will copy 3 characters.
`index + 1` means point to the character 1 after the one pointed to by `index`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot muck around with pointers in Java. Either you use `String` methods such as `subString(int startIdx, int endIdx)` to extract out substring to assign to handCeil and handFloor. I would prefer keeping them as Java `String`. If later you need to access the individual characters you could do it anyways through `charAt(int idx)` method.

Answer (score 1):

Adding one to a char* (pointer) increments the pointer one char.

So in the code provided, since index points to the '-' in handText, incrementing it will cause the pointer to now point to the next character.

(BTW, the C++ code provided isn't at all secure and will cause significant errors for many possible values of handText, like 'this is a string-'. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The snippet invokes **undefined behavior**.

```
const char* handText;
const char* index = strchr(handText, '-');
```

`handText` is an uninitialized pointer constant. Passing it as a parameter to `strchr` invokes UB. `strchr` returns the pointer to the first occurence of `-` in `handText` but `handText` is pointing no where or garbage.

Comment: I am sorry in the way I miswrote the code, but handText is theoretically one of this function's inputs. You are correct nonetheless.

Comment: @Pedro Cimini - Nothing to sorry about :) I thought you might be unaware of this but glad that you actually knew it.